# test if a variable is a primitive rather than an object?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to test a variable to see if it is a primitive?

I have seen lots of questions about testing an variable to see if it is an object, but not testing for a primitive.

This question is academic, I don't actually need to perform this test from my own code.  I'm just trying to get a deeper understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: A specific type of primitive, or just any old not-an-object primitive?

Comment: Have you tried using `typeof myVar !== 'object' && typeof myVar !== 'string'...` ?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - any old not-an-object primitive.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many questions.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To test for **any** primitive:

```
function isPrimitive(test) {
    return test !== Object(test);
}
```

Example:

```
isPrimitive(100); // true
isPrimitive(new Number(100)); // false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kieranpotts/dy791s96/

Comment: Am I right when I feel that it has a performance overhead as the price of code simplicity?

Comment: @Zoltán Tamási, yeah you are right, about 7 times slower than instanceof check

Comment: Not worth an edit, but you don't need the `;` after a function declaration (as opposed to a function *expression* like `var isPrimitive = function(test) {...};`).

Comment: Object(undefined) !== undefined is true

Comment: @Artemiy StagnantIce Alexeew Didn't you expect so? Undefined is a primitive type.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási An alternative would be `const isPrimitive = (value) => { try { "" in value; return false; } catch { return true; } };`. `… in value` never throws any errors except in the case where `value` is a primitive. Without the `catch` binding, an engine may optimize away any `TypeError` object.

Comment: @SebastianSimon A general rule that I've heard is to try and avoid using errors as a method of control flow within your codebase, not only are errors highly costly in terms of performance but they reflect something deeper needing resolution, errors are for exceptions and not ordinary behaviour - even if they just return out and resume as normal without actually interrupting the program.

Comment: @ChiaraAni can you elaborate? `isPrimitive([])` returns `false` for me, which is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I checked it wrong.

Comment: I've run this method against one using `typeof` [(example here)](https://jsfiddle.net/zgexqd14/2/) in a benchmark (inside a for loop of 10.000.00.000 iterations). The `Object()` implementation is only by 0.09% slower than using `typeof``

Answer (score 21):

`Object` accepts an argument and returns if it is an object, or returns an object otherwise.

Then, you can use a strict equality comparison, which compares types and values.

If `value` was an object, `Object(value)` will be the same object, so `value === Object(value)`. If value wasn't an object, `value !== Object(value)` because they will have different types.

So you can use

```js
Object(value) !== value
```

Comment: Am I right when I feel that it has a performance overhead as the price of code simplicity?