# TypeScript: Push to an array of Nested JSON Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I am trying to add and remove values from an array of NESTED json object. Deletion was easy but I am struggling with addition:

```
export const addNestedJson = (
  json: Record<string, any> | any[],
  value: any,
  keys: string[]
): Record<string, any> | any[] => {
  // Please pass in mutated Values before calling the function

  const isJSONArray = Array.isArray(json);
  if (keys.length === 0) {
    if (isJSONArray) {
      return [...json, value];
    }
    return json;
  }
  const key = keys.shift() as string;
  const index = key ?? 0;
  const indexKey = isNaN(+index) ? 0 : +index;
  const newJson = isJSONArray ? json[indexKey] : json[key];
  const nestedJsonValue = addNestedJson(newJson, value, keys);
  return isJSONArray
    ? [...json, nestedJsonValue]
    : { ...json, [key]: nestedJsonValue };
}
```

I am trying to use recursion as that seems to be the easiest solution, but for some reason I am not able to visualize and formulate the merge logic.

Here's what I expect:

`JSON: [], key: [], valueTobeAdded: 1 should return [1]`

`JSON: [{a: {b:[]}}], key: ['a','b'], valueTobeAdded: 1 should return [{a:{b:[1]}}]`

`JSON: [{a: {b:[{c:[4]}]}}], key: ['a','b','0','c'], valueTobeAdded: 1 should return [{a: {b:[{c:[4,1]}]}}]`

Comment: NB: What you call JSON is not all JSON. These are objects/arrays, and apparently even instances of a specific class `Record`. So just drop the term `JSON` from your code and variable names. JSON is a text format for transferring data.

Comment: `Record` is a built-in type :x

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, @kellys. As this was not tagged with typescript, I looked at this with JavaScript eyes, but anyway, something that is typed any different than a string should not be called JSON, except for [`JSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)

Comment: In the second example, why would that have to produce what you say? The top level is an array, and `a` is not (yet) defined on that array...

Comment: Yes, as @trincot says, in your second and third examples you should pass `['0','a','b']` and `['0','a','b','0','c']`, respectively, as keys.

Comment: This is really just: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects and arrays by string path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)(after the split), [Javascript: Get deep value from object by passing path to it as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817394/javascript-get-deep-value-from-object-by-passing-path-to-it-as-string) or lodash [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get), [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303609/13762301)

Comment: @pilchard, I think the Asker wants a different behaviour than lodash `set`, as they want a value to be appended to an array when the end of the path is an array (instead of replacing that array with the new value).

Comment: Then it would just be a `_.get` with a push. `_.get(object, keys).push(value);`

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think that the last two examples of expected output do not define a correct `key`. Since the inputs are *arrays* at their top level, and you expect the first array value to be replaced, you should have 0 as the first entry in the `key`.

In the code I see two issues and have a few more remarks:

1. In case `keys` is the empty array, and the data is not an array, it should be *replaced* by the new value, so instead of `return json`, you should `return value`
2. When coming back from the recursive call, and the current level is an array, the new value should not be *appended* to the array, but instead be the replacement value for what was at `indexKey`.
3. Not a real problem, but I would not mutate `keys`.
4. Not a problem with the algorithm, but the name `json` in your property and variable names is not appropriate. JSON is something you would have to pass to `JSON.parse`. Anything else should not be called JSON.

This results in the following adapted code:

```
const addNested = (
  data: Record<string, any> | any[],
  value: any,
  keys: string[]
): Record<string, any> | any[] => {
  const isArray = Array.isArray(data);
  if (keys.length === 0) {
    if (isArray) {
      return [...data, value];
    }
    return value; // Overwrite any data
  }
  // Don't mutate keys with shift
  const key = keys[0] as string;
  const indexKey = +key || 0;
  const newData = isArray ? data[indexKey] : data[key];
  const nestedValue = addNested(newData, value, keys.slice(1));
  return isArray
    ? Object.assign([], data, { [indexKey]: nestedValue }) // Replace at index
    : { ...data, [key]: nestedValue };
}
```

```js
const addNested = (
  data /*: Record<string, any> | any[] */,
  value /*: any */,
  keys /*: string[] */
) /*: Record<string, any> | any[] */ => {
  const isArray = Array.isArray(data);
  if (keys.length === 0) {
    if (isArray) {
      return [...data, value];
    }
    return value; // Overwrite any data
  }
  // Don't mutate keys with shift
  const key = keys[0] /* as string */;
  const indexKey = +key || 0;
  const newData = isArray ? data[indexKey] : data[key];
  const nestedValue = addNested(newData, value, keys.slice(1));
  return isArray
    ? Object.assign([], data, { [indexKey]: nestedValue }) // Replace at index
    : { ...data, [key]: nestedValue };
}

console.log(addNested([], 1, [])); //  [1]
console.log(addNested([{a: {b:[]}}], 1, [0,'a','b'])); // [{a:{b:[1]}}]
console.log(addNested([{a: {b:[{c:[4]}]}}], 1, [0,'a','b','0','c'])); // [{a: {b:[{c:[4,1]}]}}]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed explanation! This really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Couple of advices when working with algorithms:

1. Recursion is actually quite hard for a human brain. Although I agree that some tasks are easier if you know how to apply recursion. Especially in case of nested recursion.
2. Naming is really important.

So for example, for me, "keys" is quite confusing. If I revisit this function later, I would probably think at first that I should add the value to all of these keys. So I would rather rename the variable into smth like "keyPath".

Now, I'll try to explain how I would solve it. This is probably not the best solution, just something from the top of my head.

So, imagine we have a nested object:

```js
{
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: []
        }
    }
}
```

And then, let's imagine the simplest scenario, we need to insert a value all the way to `key3`.

In this case, obviously `keyPath=["key1", "key2", "key3"]`

Now, in order to reach the last key, we can start with first key of the path, and try to go down into the object until we reach the end of `keyPath`.

1. take first element of keyPath. `const key = "key1";`
2. go deeper into our object: `const nestedObj = obj[key];`
3. repeat, but now use `nestedObj` instead of `obj`, and "key2", and so forth

This can be a recursion, but I think it's a simple loop, isn't it?

```js
for (const i=0; i<keyPath.length; i++) {
   const key = keyPath[i];
   const newObj = obj[key];
   obj = newObj;
}
```

This code is a bit too verbose though. We can simplify it like this:

```js
for (const key of keyPath) {
    obj = obj[key];
}
```

And voila, we got to the final object where we can insert the element:

```js
obj.push(value);
```

So the whole function would look like this:

```js
function addNested(obj: any, keyPath: (string|number)[], value: any) {
    for (const key of keyPath)
        obj = obj[key];
    obj.push(value);
}
```

This will already satisfy all of the test cases you had, but as I understood your code, there is one more possibility: last key in the keyPath doesn't exist or is a primitive value (i.e. not an object and not an array).

Well, when we loop into the object, if the key doesn't exist, our `obj[key]` will return `undefined`. And we can also check [if it contains a primitive value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31538091/361687) or `null`.

So in this case, we know that we reached the end of the object, and we simply need to assign our value.

```js
if (typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' || obj[key] === null || obj[key] !== Object(obj[key])) {
    obj[key] = value;
    return;
}
```

`typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' || obj[key] === null` can be simplified into `obj[key] == null` (notice it's `==` and **not** `===`).

So the function becomes something like this:

```js
function addNested(obj: any, keyPath: (string|number)[], value: any) {
    for (const key of keyPath) {
        if (obj[key] == null || obj[key] !== Object(obj[key])) {
            obj[key] = value;
            return;
        }
        obj = obj[key];
    }
    obj.push(value);
}
```

This is still not ideal algorithm, because it doesn't do any error checking. For example, if more than 1 key from the keyPath doesn't exist in the object, or keyPath ends with an object, it doesn't handle that.

Still, I hope that this example will help you to improve approach to working with algorithms :)

Comment: Thank you very much this was indeed extremely helpful! :)